# nested tab gwtp

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I posted a question the other day and didn't get much response. I have tried a few things but still no luck. I am trying to nest a tab presenter in GWTP. I have one frame (North) that is tab group 1 and one frame (West) that is tab group 2. When I interact with group 1 I update the nested tab presenter which controls group 2. I have looked at the example for nested tab presenters but I have been unable to determine my error from it.

The two TabContainerPresenters are ManagementTabsPresenter and SettingsTabsPresenter. The children of these are like the HomePresenter below. The content for these children is displayed in the center of a DockLayoutPanel located in the MainPreseter. I want the ManagementTabsPresenter and the SettingsTabsPresenter to be displayed in the West slot of the same DockLayoutPanel.

When I run this code everything is placed on the screen in the correct locations. You can even click the tabs and have actions occur. The problems start in that the SettingsPresenter is displayed first even though the default page is the HomePresenter. It's like it tries to reveal both at the same time on start up. Then when you selected any of the tabs which are part of the ManagementTabsPresenter or the SettingsTabsPresenter  It opens the correct content in the MainPresenter.Center_Slot but the incorrect presenter is displayed in the MainPresenter.West_Slot. I can't figure out what's going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public class HomePresenter extends Presenter<HomePresenter.MyView, HomePresenter.MyProxy> {
@Inject
AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager;

@NameToken(NameTokens.homePage)
@ProxyStandard
@NoGatekeeper
public interface MyProxy extends TabContentProxyPlace<HomePresenter> {
}

public interface MyView extends View {
}

@TabInfo(container = ManagementTabsPresenter.class)
static TabData getTabLabel(MainAppGinjector injector) {
    return new TabDataBasic("home", 0);
}

@Inject
public HomePresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
}

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, ManagementTabsPresenter.TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, this);
}
}





public class ManagementTabsPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<ManagementTabsPresenter.MyView, ManagementTabsPresenter.MyProxy> {

/**
 * {@link ManagementTabsPresenter}'s proxy.
 */
@ProxyStandard
public interface MyProxy extends NonLeafTabContentProxy<ManagementTabsPresenter> {
}

/**
 * {@link ManagementTabsPresenter}'s view.
 */
public interface MyView extends TabView {
}

/**
 * Use this in leaf presenters, inside their {@link #revealInParent} method.
 */
@ContentSlot
public static final GwtEvent.Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT = MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT;


/**
 * This will be the event sent to our "unknown" child presenters, in order for
 * them to register their tabs.
 */
@RequestTabs
public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> TYPE_Management_RequestTabs = new Type<RequestTabsHandler>();

@TabInfo(container = HeaderTabsPresenter.class, nameToken = NameTokens.homePage)
static TabData getTabLabel(MainAppGinjector injector) {
    return new TabDataBasic("Management", 0);
}

@Inject
public ManagementTabsPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
                               final MyProxy proxy,  AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy,TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, TYPE_Management_RequestTabs);
}


@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this,  HeaderTabsPresenter.TYPE_VERTICAL_TABS_SLOT, this);
}
}



public class SettingsTabsPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<SettingsTabsPresenter.MyView, SettingsTabsPresenter.MyProxy> {

/**
 * {@link SettingsTabsPresenter}'s proxy.
 */
@ProxyStandard
public interface MyProxy extends NonLeafTabContentProxy<SettingsTabsPresenter> {
}

/**
 * {@link SettingsTabsPresenter}'s view.
 */
public interface MyView extends TabView {
}

@TabInfo(container = HeaderTabsPresenter.class, nameToken = NameTokens.appUserCollectionPage)
static TabData getTabLabel(MainAppGinjector injector) {
    return new TabDataBasic("Settings", 1);
}

/**
 * Use this in leaf presenters, inside their {@link #revealInParent} method.
 */
@ContentSlot
public static final GwtEvent.Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT = MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT;


/**
 * This will be the event sent to our "unknown" child presenters, in order for
 * them to register their tabs.
 */
@RequestTabs
public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> TYPE_Settings_RequestTabs = new Type<RequestTabsHandler>();

@Inject
public SettingsTabsPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
                               final MyProxy proxy,  AppPlaceManager appPlaceManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy,TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, TYPE_Settings_RequestTabs);
}


@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this,  HeaderTabsPresenter.TYPE_VERTICAL_TABS_SLOT, this);
}
}


public class HeaderTabsPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<HeaderTabsPresenter.MyView, HeaderTabsPresenter.MyProxy> {
@Inject EventBus eventBus;

/**
 * {@link HeaderTabsPresenter}'s proxy.
 */
@ProxyStandard
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<HeaderTabsPresenter> {
}

/**
 * {@link HeaderTabsPresenter}'s view.
 */
public interface MyView extends TabView {
    void changeTab(Tab tab, TabData tabData, String historyToken);
}

/**
 * This will be the event sent to our "unknown" child presenters, in order for
 * them to register their tabs.
 */
@RequestTabs
public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> TYPE_HEADER_RequestTabs = new Type<RequestTabsHandler>();

/**
 * Fired by child proxie's when their tab content is changed.
 */
@ChangeTab
public static final Type<ChangeTabHandler> TYPE_HEADER_ChangeTab = new Type<ChangeTabHandler>();

@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_VERTICAL_TABS_SLOT = MainPresenter.WEST_SLOT;

@Inject
public HeaderTabsPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view,
                           final MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, TYPE_VERTICAL_TABS_SLOT, TYPE_HEADER_RequestTabs, TYPE_HEADER_ChangeTab);
}


@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
     RevealContentEvent.fire(this, MainPresenter.NORTH_SLOT, this);
}

}



public class MainPresenter extends Presenter<MainPresenter.MyView, MainPresenter.MyProxy>{

@Inject VSMRequestFactory requestFactory;
@Inject VSMMessages vsmMessages;
@Inject VSMExceptionMessages vsmExceptionMessages;
@Inject EventBus eventBus;

@ProxyStandard
@NoGatekeeper
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<MainPresenter> {
}

public interface MyView extends View {

}

@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> SOUTH_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> WEST_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> CENTER_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();
@ContentSlot
public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> NORTH_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();

@Inject
public MainPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
}

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealRootLayoutContentEvent.fire(this, this);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    initializeAppUser();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon something similar before... I think it is because both of them inherit from TabContainerPresenter and that there is a bug in gwtp that calls onReveal() on the wrong inherited child.

take a look at this gwtp forum post:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/gwt-platform/gilad$20egozi/gwt-platform/p0s3BlN-ceE/5EL3nynaiu4J](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/gwt-platform/gilad%2420egozi/gwt-platform/p0s3BlN-ceE/5EL3nynaiu4J)

Is that the case? if so, I don't think anyone filed a bug on the gwtp issue tracker, so let me know.

(of-course, the best check is not to inherit and see if its working)

Comment: I worked around this problem by having my child tabs fire the reveal in the MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT and also firing a reveal of the nested tabs presenter (Management or Settings) with an unused RevealContentHandler.

Comment: So my TabContainerPresenter's contain public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> TYPE_SETTINGS_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT =  new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>(); and my child presenters look like this  @Override
    protected void revealInParent() {
        RevealContentEvent.fire(this, MainPresenter.CENTER_SLOT, this);
        RevealContentEvent.fire(this, ManagementTabsPresenter.TYPE_MAIN_CONTENT_SLOT, this);
    }